# Can I see step by step how this is done?

Tags: logic

How do we go from $P \lor Q = \lnot (P \downarrow Q)$

$P\lor Q = (P\downarrow Q) \downarrow (P\downarrow Q)$ to this
I understand they are equivalent, but I don't get how it went from this $\lnot (P \downarrow Q)$ to $(P\downarrow Q) \downarrow (P\downarrow Q)$. To be more specific let's say I wanted to see how you added 450 and 900 together, did you put 450 first then added 900, did you use mental math, did you regroup, etc. I am wanting to see the mathematical steps basically of how it was done. This is also straight out of Daniel J Velleman's "How To Prove It: A Structured Approach"

Comment: What is $\downarrow$?

Comment: It means neither "     " nor "    "

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey,  look at the bottom of the page [NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR), you'll get the answer

Comment: I've tried converting $\lnot (P \downarrow Q)$ to $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$

Comment: Essentially from wild_fox's link.

 Step 1. By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Definition) and the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Truth_table), $P \downarrow Q = \neg(P \lor Q)$.
 Step 2. $\lnot (P \downarrow Q)=\lnot (\neg(P \lor Q))=P \lor Q$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a general fact that $\neg A$ is the same as $A\downarrow A$, as a simple truth table will show.

Now apply this with $A=P\downarrow Q$.

Answer (score 0):

The tautology $A\downarrow A \equiv \neg A$ seems to be the part you're missing.